# set focus in button when open popup in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I'm having problem to set the focus on a button to open a popup.
      The button gets the focus, but it does not get the appearance that focu.
      It is as if no component was the focu.

My source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600">


<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import comps.MyPopUpWindow;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        // declare a variable for the reusable custom PopUp Window
        private var popup:MyPopUpWindow;

        private function openPopUpWindow(evt:FlexEvent=null):void {
            // open the PopUp Window as a modal popup window
            // and store it in a variable for later use
            popup = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,MyPopUpWindow,true)  as MyPopUpWindow;
        }

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            openPopUpWindow();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Button click="button1_clickHandler(event)" label="Open popup"/>  
</s:Application>
```

The Popup:

```
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
            width="400" height="300"
            layout="vertical"
            title="Title"
            showCloseButton="true"                                                          
            keyDown="titlewindow1_keyDownHandler(event)"
            close="titlewindow1_closeHandler(event)"
  creationComplete="titlewindow1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">       

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.core.IFlexDisplayObject;
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.managers.IFocusManagerComponent;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

protected function titlewindow1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            login.setFocus();                           
            var componente:Button = focusManager.getFocus() as Button;
//Alert.show(componente.name ,'Save'); to ensure that the component holds the focu.                     
        }           

protected function titlewindow1_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
if (event.charCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE) {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseEvent(CloseEvent.CLOSE));
            }
        }

        protected function titlewindow1_closeHandler(event:CloseEvent):void
        {
        PopUpManager.removePopUp(event.target as IFlexDisplayObject);
        }


        protected function save_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER) 
                Alert.show('Login','Login');            
        }

        protected function login_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show('Login','Login');            
        }       
    ]]>
</fx:Script>    


<mx:Button id="login" label="Login"     click="login_clickHandler(event)"/>

<mx:Button id="cancel" label="Cancel" />            

</mx:TitleWindow>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You've included a lot of code; you may consider trying tobe a bit more focused.  I do not see a place where you try to set the focus.

Comment: Hello. Trying is the method creationComplete="titlewindow1_creationCompleteHandler(event)" in the <mx:TitleWindow>  .

Answer (score 0):

Better manually you dispatch the event on particular button.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ce1.html

Answer (score 0):

I got through a simple, but do not know why it worked. When I open the popup, I focu  configured the first and then the TextInput and after in the Button.